# How to convert Google Auth User to Phone Auth Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Android app, I was using Google Email Auth verification using Firebase. Now I want to use Phone Auth. Is it possible to convert the old user who had signed in using Google mail to phone auth verified user? This is my code which uses Google Auth-

```
private void createAccount() {

    // Choose authentication providers
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Collections.singletonList( new 

AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build() );

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult( AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setIsSmartLockEnabled(false).setAvailableProviders(providers).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);

        showProgress();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

I am using Firebase Auth UI library-

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'
```